# Did anyone integrate Xquery plugin in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, xquery, marklogic

Did anyone succeeded in  integration of Xquery plugin in sonarqube.
I have tried to integrate the xquery plugin available "https://github.com/malteseduck/sonar-xquery-plugin" in github but no luck

Comment: The plugin is out of date.  I had looked at updating it, but they have horrible support of using Antlr4 that is available at https://github.com/xqdoc/xqdoc